# Error: uses or override a deprecated API

Tags: java, api, netbeans, compilar, jni

Tengo una pequeña duda sobre un programa que maneja las transacciones de diferentes terceros de una tienda. Aparentemente el código funciona bien y todo, pero al momento de dar clic en "Clean and build", me sale la siguiente línea de advertencia

Note: C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\tercerosTienda\src\tercerostienda\frmLogin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

Empiezo a creer que por ese error, al momento de ejecutar el programa, me sale el siguiente mensaje "ERROR:A JNI error has ocurred, please check your installation and try again", seguido de otra ventana que dice: "A Java Exception has ocurred".

Por favor necesito alguna ayuda para mejorar esto. Dejo el código en cuestión de la clase que genera ese problema:

private void btnIniciarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
    String user;
    String password;
    
    user = txtUsuario.getText();
    password = txtContraseña.getText();
    
    if(user.equals("admin")&& password.equals("1234")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Datos ingresados correctamente");  
        panelPrincipal jfr = new panelPrincipal();
    jfr.setVisible(true);  
    dispose(); 
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Usuario o contraseña incorrectos", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        txtUsuario.setText("");
        txtContraseña.setText("");
    }
    
}
```

(Solamente dejo este fragmento de código, puesto que lo otro son las líneas de código que genera Netbeans automáticamente para cada clase).